# Zeros of a Polynomial and maximum principle

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $P: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ be a non-constant polynomial and $c>0$. Let $\Omega =\{z\in\mathbb C : |P(z)|<c\}$.

I can't understand how does the maximum principle implies that every connected component of $\Omega$ contains at least one zero of $P$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U$ be a connected component of $\Omega$. Then we have $\lvert P(z)\rvert = c$ on $\partial U$ - if $\lvert P(z_0)\rvert \neq c$, then there is an $r > 0$  with $\lvert P(z) - P(z_0)\rvert < \bigl\lvert \lvert P(z)\rvert-c\bigr\rvert$ for $\lvert z-z_0\rvert < r$, and the disk $D_r(z_0)$ is either completely contained in $U$ or doesn't intersect $U$ at all.

Since $P$ is non-constant, $\Omega$, and hence $U$, is bounded. By definition, we have $\lvert P(z)\rvert < c$ on $U$. So if $P$ had no zero in $U$, the function

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{P(z)}$$

would be holomorphic in the bounded open set $U$, continuous on $\overline{U}$, and satisfy

$$\lvert f(z)\rvert > \frac{1}{c} = \sup_{\zeta\in\partial U} \lvert f(\zeta)\rvert,$$

for some (all) $z\in U$, which contradicts the maximum principle.

Comment: Thank you! I think z shoud be changed with z_0 in the second part of the inequality (line 2), isn't it?